# Is there a size variant in Xcode's interface builder to target smaller iPhones?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, size-classes

Is there a size variant to target smaller iPhones in portrait (iPhone 7 and below)?

Width Compact covers all iPhones.

[image: Xcode Interface builder size variant bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the concept of size classes is not as fine-grained as that. As you rightly say, compact width embraces all iPhones (except the Plus phones in landscape). If you want to do something based on what size iPhone this actually is, you'll have to look directly at the screen dimensions or other determinant, in code; Apple discourages this kind of behavior, but some apps do it.

Comment: Sizes classes definitely needed be adjusted for the growth in phone dimensions. It is a fault that size classes were implemented with categorizing all iPhones in the same class. The new iPhones are almost twice as big as older devices. Designing for an iPhone 7 compared to the iPhone 4 is not the same and shouldn't be placed into the same group. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you feel strongly about the matter, please file an enhancement request with Apple! http://bugreport.apple.com (Actually I think the situation is much worse on the iPad, where the size classes don't change on rotation, but a compact width could mean anything down to an incredibly tall-and-narrow 3-to-1 height-to-width ratio.)